# VS 2010 & Oracle 11g ORA 12514

Tags: c#, database, oracle

I knew, there are thousands of topics similar to mine. I read them all. Nothing works for me. And there I will describe my problem: I created a Oracle database using Oracle SQL developer setting values:

```
connection name: test,
username: bob, 
password: qwerty 
Connection type: basic,
role: default, 
Hostname: localhost, 
port: 1521, 
SID : orcl
```

Reason I'm writing all of this is that I really did everything possible, and I hope that by providing each kind of data someone will be able to help me.

My next step was downloading and installing ODAC 11.2 Release 4 (11.2.0.3.0) with Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio.

When I want make a connection to database from my application using server explorer I'm entering following data:

```
data source name: //localhost:1521/test
user name: ADMIN
password : qwerty
```

connection name is being set automatically.

When I'm trying to test connection I'm getting ORA 12514... and here it is how I changed my tnsname.ora:

```
LISTENER_ORCL =
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))

orcl =
 (DESCRIPTION = 
   (ADDRESS_LIST =
     (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
   )
 (CONNECT_DATA =
   (SERVICE_NAME = orcl)
 )
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure of the following:

1. Oracle service is running on windows.
2. Your pfile or spfile has local_listener='LISTENER_ORCL'
3. change the orcl config in tnsname.ora as :

ORCL =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = orcl)
    )
  )